# Web.config not being read (VS 2010)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I have a ASP.Net Web Application which connects to a SQL Server. The `web.config` has `<connectionStrings/>`. It appears `web.config` is not being read at runtime, and it's causing data bound controls to fail at runtime with "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

My connection string uses a System DSN, and appears to follow [connectionStrings Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The DSN tests properly, and when I use the connection string from `web.config` on a control's property, all works well.

EDIT: Its blowing up on the Visual Studio generated line `grvSysStatus.DataBind()`
. Here's the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvSysStatus" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="95%" showHeader="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="message_text" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jeff

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MasterTraq_Dev"
         connectionString="Dsn=MasterTraq_Dev;uid=xxxxx;pwd=yyyyy;trusted_connection=No;app=Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010;wsid=zzzzz;database=MasterTraq_Dev"
         providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
         />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That connection string looks so wrong.

I've not used a DSN since classic ASP days but I'm pretty sure it didn't allow a 'registered trademark' character in it.

Have a look at [connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) perhaps?

Comment: Lol.... Visual Studio created the string when I selected the DSN from the drop down :)

Comment: I tried one of the samples strings from the URL with no joy. Visual Studio (or the web server emulator) acts like its not reading the config file: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized". Why does it need the property set (in hundreds of places) if its in `web.config`? Centralized Administration was the whole point of moving it to `web.config`.

Comment: What's the actual datasource?

Comment: "What's the actual datasource?" - A SQL Server on another machine. The test string is/was `connectionString= "server=XXXXX;database=MasterTraq_Dev;uid=YYYYY;pwd=ZZZZZ"`

Comment: I don't think you need a DSN then, just a standard Sql Client connection string: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MasterTraq_Dev" connectionString= "server=XXXXX;database=MasterTraq_Dev;uid=YYYYY;pwd=ZZZZZ"/>  
</connectionStrings>